# Convert CSV to Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, vim, csv

Any ideas on how to convert this CSV into a ruby array using vim?

Starting CSV:

```
Year,Make,Model
1997,Ford,E350
2000,Mercury,Cougar
```

Desired Array:

```
car_info = [
  {'Year' => '1997', 'Make' => 'Ford', 'Model' => 'E350'},
  {'Year' => '2000', 'Make' => 'Mercury', 'Model' => 'Cougar'},
]
```

I have > 2000 entries like the CSV above, and I'd love a way to quickly re-format it for use in my Rails app. I'd like to use vim, but I'm open to other options too.

Comment: Why don't you just read the file in and convert it to the object you want using Ruby?

Comment: That's a good idea -- could you post an example in the answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FasterCSV.read("path/to/file.csv", :headers => true).map do |row|
  { "Year" => row[0], "Make" => row[1], "Model" => row[2] }
end
```

PS: Install `faster_csv` gem

Comment: +1. You could also use `:headers => true` when reading the CSV.

Comment: Awesome. This looks more promising than doing it by hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In vim, you can use global search and replace with a regular expression:

```
:g/\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)/s//{'Year' => '\1', 'Make' => '\2', 'Model' => '\3'}/g
```

Then edit the first and last lines of the resulting file accordingly.

Comment: Thanks -- this looks like a good solution. Didn't know you could combine search with regex.